# How to map returned Observable from Http call in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

The below code returns an empty array, and I'm having trouble understanding why. What is the standard practice for pushing objects to an array from a return Observable?

In jobServices.ts:

```
 getCities(city){
  return this.http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=70d86e78cabf44f710fd89936c709750`)
 }
```

In Home.ts

```js
cities = ["Atlanta", "Chicago", "New York", "Los Angeles", "San 
   Diego", "Athens", "Miami", "Nashville", "Austin", "Amsterdam", 
   "Paris" ]
citiesPayload = []



constructor(public jobService: JobService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.returnCities();
}

returnCities(){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++){
        this.jobService.getCities(this.cities[i])
            .subscribe(city => {
                this.citiesPayload.push(city);
            });
        }
    console.log(this.citiesPayload)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, you need to add the HTTP requests into an array then use an operator like [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). Then you can `subscribe` to that newly returned stream.

```js
import {
  forkJoin
} from 'rxjs';
class ExampleClass {
  cities = [
    "Atlanta",
    "Chicago",
    "New York",
    "Los Angeles",
    "San Diego",
    "Athens",
    "Miami",
    "Nashville",
    "Austin",
    "Amsterdam",
    "Paris"
  ];
  constructor(public jobService: JobService) {}




  ngOnInit() {
    this.returnCities()
  }

  returnCities() {
    const cityObservables = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cities.length; i++) {
      cityObservables.push(this.jobService.getCities(this.cities[i]));
    }
    forkJoin(cityObservables).subscribe(resp => {
      // city data here
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }

  getCities(city) {
    return this.http.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=70d86e78cabf44f710fd89936c709750`)
  }
}
```

Adding a [stackblitz-demo](https://angular-forkjoin-example.stackblitz.io) included are the suggestions of @RichardMatsen & @eric99.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';

import {
  Observable,
  forkJoin,
  of
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  catchError
} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  todos: number[] = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
  viewValues: Todo[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  getTodos() {
    const todos = this.todos.map(t => this.http.get < Todo > (`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${t}`));
    forkJoin(todos).pipe(catchError(err => of (err))).subscribe(resp => this.viewValues = resp);
  }
}


export interface Todo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use Array.map like this `const cityObservables = this.cities.map(city => this.jobService.getCities(city))` or shorter equivalent `const cityObservables = this.cities.map(this.jobService.getCities)`

Comment: Note that `forkJoin` is fragile - if one of the cities is unknown, you get nothing in the subscribe. Add `this.http.get(...).pipe(catchError(err => of(err) ))` to handle individual get errors.

Comment: @RichardMatsen & eric99 excellent suggestions. I've updated for posterity.